# Sonarcloud scanning fails on Quality gate

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1

After solving problem `The version of Java (11.0.19) used to run this analysis is deprecated, and SonarCloud no longer supports it. Please upgrade to Java 17 or later.` new error occured on next step, on Quality gate step.

```
true
— Wait for SonarQube analysis to be completed and return quality gate status
<1s
[2024-01-18T14:23:06.594Z] Checking status of SonarQube task 'AY0c9B_ILTqpqoTFXhjP' on server 'SonarCloud'

[2024-01-18T14:23:06.646Z] SonarQube task 'AY0c9B_ILTqpqoTFXhjP' status is 'SUCCESS'

[2024-01-18T14:23:06.687Z] SonarQube task 'AY0c9B_ILTqpqoTFXhjP' completed. Quality gate is 'ERROR'

Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ERROR
```

Could have previous problem caused this issue? also, this problem happens on some services, and On old good code too, which have passed quality gate in the past.

This happens mostly on code, which hasn't been built for some time, so I turned of qulity gate step in my jenkins groovy pipeline, iy built and deployed succesfull and when I turned it on, still same error.